# Infijo a posfijo en Java

Tags: java

Solo separe operandos en una pila y operadores en otra pila, pero no se el paso final a posfija... ayuda.

```
public boolean lectura(){
    a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la expresion");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){

        char n=a.charAt(i);   


        if(n=='+' || n=='-' || n=='*' || n=='/' || n=='^' || n=='(' || n==')'){
             pila2.push(n);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " "+pila2+"\n"
                + "Tope = "+pila2.size()+"\n Pila 2");
        }else{
             pila1.push(a.charAt(i));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " "+pila1+"\n"
                + "Tope = "+pila1.size()+"\n Pila 1");
         }

        pila3.push(n);

    }
    return true;
}//FIN DEL METODO LECTURA
```

Comment: No se entiende cual es tu problema. Por favor acláralo.

Comment: Como se hace para que por jerarquia los que estan en la pila de operadores pasen a la pila de los operandos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está es que estás haciendo mal la inclusión de los elementos en la expresión. estás incluyendo los operadores indiscriminadamente en las pilas, cuando hay condiciones:

lo primero que necesitamos saber es que los operados tienen prioridades asociadas que son utilizadas para su administración, básicamente este es la prioridad de los operadores:

```
Operador     | Prioridad dentro de la pila | prioridad fuera de la pila
^ (potencia) | 3                           | 4
*,/          | 2                           | 2
+,-          | 1                           | 1
(            | 0                           | 5
```

ahora teniendo esto en cuenta el algoritmo viene el siguiente: tratare de explicarlo paso a paso.

```
 1. mientras queden elementos en la expresión infija leer elemento y 
 hacer del paso 2 al 4:

 2.si elemento es un operando va directo a la expresión.
 3.si no, (el elemento es un caracter) entonces:
       3.1 si la pila de ayuda está vacía almaceno el caracter y  
       vuelvo a (1)

       3.2 si la pila no está vacía entonces
       (aquí hay dos opciones)

            3.2.1 si la prioridad del operador es mayor que la prioridad
                  del elemento en la sima de la pila, se almacena en la 
                  la pila y se vuelve a (1)

            3.2.1 si la prioridad es menor entonces saco el elemento de 
                  la pila y lo envío a la expresión, y almaceno en la pila
                  el carácter leído.

 4. si es paréntesis derecho (observar que el derecho no se encuentra en 
    los operadores ) entonces:

     4.1 saco elementos de la pila de operadores hasta encontrar el 
     paréntesis izquierdo, y todos los elementos extraídos van a la 
     expresión potsfija en el orden que fueron obtenidos.

     4.2 continuar a partir de 1.

 5. en este punto ya no hay mas elementos en la expresión infija.

 6. si quedan operadores en la pila sacar todos e incluirlos en la    
 expresión potsfija.
```

y listo. ese serial el algoritmo, solo tienes que crear en tu código la lógica para validar la prioridad de cada operador.